# How I can stop the webpages refresh itself (at least some portion of the content)?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, browser, websocket

I am wondering how I can stop the webpage from refreshing itself?

I am using Safari or Chrome to connect to wsj.com or Yahoo finance. I found that the webpage can refresh itself or some number are constantly changing (for example, for wsj.com, the indices at the front of the page change every 5 seconds).

How I might ask my browser to stop refreshing itself except simply close the web browser at all or disconnect the network?

Comment: Websockets or sending an AJAX request every few seconds or so.

Comment: @Spectric Do you mean that as a client, just type the url and the browser will do the remaining heavy lifting such as connect the websockets for me and send ajax request? I am wondering is there a breakdown of such workflow using Chrome? I really want to know what is the wss url of the websocket my browser is trying to connect to.

Comment: Simple Javascript on a timer can query the server for new data, and then update/append the page.  To stop it, simply disconnect from the internet.

Comment: This question is likely to be closed unless you remove the word "why" from it.  If your question is truly just "how can I get my browser to stop refreshing itself" then just ask that.  Don't conflate it with issues of "why".  Those are opinionated web-design decisions.  FYI, in Chrome, you can open your browser and type the word `debugger` in the console, and it will halt JavaScript processing on the page - preventing it from refreshing (in case you want to examine the page in its current state or something like that.)

Answer (score 1):

The reason a web page keeps refreshing itself is that it's using a  tag that automatically refreshes the page depends on the time provided in the script

E.g.

```
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">

</head>
```

The Value inside the Content"5" is the seconds it will take the web page to refresh.

reference: W3School
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It could be a solution. But the webpage does not refresh totally. Just some portion of the content got modified.

Answer (score 0):

When you visit a website, you give it permission to run code on a browser tab and communicate between your computer and it's server. thats all the permission it needs. You can go to chrome://flags or edge://flags to turn off stuff like websockets

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got nothing when I type in ```chrome://tabs```. I got ```This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at chrome://tabs/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.``` Would you mind telling more about how I might shut down websockets?

Comment: my mistake. was supposed to be chrome://flags